# How to monitor playback on ALSA via asoundlib?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, sampling

I'm building an application that allows for ALSA configuration and in the GUI there is a peek meter that allows the client to see playback levels in realtime. I'm having a hard time determining what device to connect to because I don't know if ALSA has a default "loopback" or not and what it's called. I am also having trouble converting the read data into a sample, then finding said sample's amplitude. Here is what I have built so far:
Grab device and set hardware params

```
if (0 == snd_pcm_open(&pPcm, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, SND_PCM_NONBLOCK))
{
    if (0 == snd_pcm_set_params(pPcm, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED, 1, 96000, 1, 1)) // This last argument confuses me because I'm not given a unit of measurement (second, millisecond, mircosecond, etc.)
    {
        return snd_pcm_start(pPcm);
    }
}

pPcm = nullptr;
return -1;
```

Read from device and return the peek of the audio signal

```
int iRtn = -1;
if (nullptr == pPcm)
{
    if (-1 == SetupListener())
    {
        return iRtn;
    }
}

// Check to make the state is sane for reading.
if (SND_PCM_STATE_PREPARED == snd_pcm_state(pPcm) ||
        SND_PCM_STATE_RUNNING == snd_pcm_state(pPcm))
{
    snd_pcm_resume(pPcm); // This might be superfluous.

    // The state is sane, read from the stream.
    signed short iBuffer = 0;
    int iNumRead = snd_pcm_readi(pPcm, &iBuffer, 1);

    if (0 < iNumRead)
    {
        // This calculates an approximation.
        // We have some audio data, acquire it's peek in dB. (decibels)
        float nSample = static_cast<float>(iBuffer);
        float nAmplitude = nSample / MAX_AMPLITUDE_S16; // MAX_AMPLITUDE_S16 is defined as "32767"
        float nDecibels = (0 < nAmplitude) ? 20 * log10(nAmplitude) : 0;
        iRtn = static_cast<int>(nDecibels); // Cast to integer for GUI element.
    }
}

return iRtn;
```

The ALSA documentation seems very barren and so I apologize if I'm misusing the API.

Comment: In looking at the PCM Interface docs, I see something called "Scope Plugin", what does that do? Is that what I would want to use to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Do you have control over the application(s) playing sounds?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm trying to get playback from the "Master" channel and monitor it. I didn't think I would need to have control over the playing applications as I'm trying to get monitor all sounds playing.

Comment: If your hardware does not support monitoring, you have to insert a monitoring plugin into the playback path.

Comment: How do I check if it does? And if it doesn't, how would I go about inserting/removing said plugin?